# Can't run dotnet .exe on client pc built on host pc

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I built my dotnet project on host pc with:
`dotnet publish --configuration Release`

I was able to run the built app on host pc without problems. Next I want to copy the app to a client pc and run it their as well.

When I try to execute the app on my client pc I got the following error:

> A fatal error occurred. The required library hostfxr.dll could not be found.

The `hostfxr.dll` is located under my installed dotnet folder.

I already set a `DOTNET_ROOT` variable pointing to my dotnet folder.

Does anyone have a clue why it is not working?

---

My host pc has following versions installed:

```
OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19041
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.402\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.8
  Commit:  9c1330dedd

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.508 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

---

My client pc has the following versions installed:

```
OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17763
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\sdk\3.1.403\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.9
  Commit:  774fc3d6a9

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.403 [C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.9 [C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.9 [C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.9 [C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

---

Is it because of built dotnet app with **3.1.402** does not run under **3.1.403**?

Comment: perhaps you're missing the hosting bundle on your target pc? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1 Do you use kestrel?

Comment: Did you try to publish a self-container app using `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release`?

Comment: I dont use IIS but want to try it in future. Do you recommand to use IIS?

Comment: Ok publish as self-contained solved it for me. "dotnet publish Project.sln -c Release --self-contained true -r win10-x64"